# Opening a question that answer another question

Tags: discussion

I got my question closed ( I don't agree with the reason - but was flagged as "off-topic" because not enough details supplied by me)

Now -after much research - I have great answer I want to contribute back to the community - including details and examples - but the question is closed - I can't answer myself.

Tried to contact few people that voted to close it - none replied.

Is it ok to Post a new question that describe the problem - and answer it self, and flag it as an answer?

Answer (score 9):

If you repost the same question, it will have the same end result as the currently closed one: it will get closed. Off-topic questions with an answer are still off-topic questions.

The thing you should do is already stated in the close reason: edit your question into shape so it is a question that can be answered by you, and other members of the community.

If your question wasn't clear as it is now, an answer will not make it better. Future users who don't understand your question can't benefit from the answer. So, first things first: edit that question!

Answer (score 7):

You should edit the question to address the problems with it, and turn it into a *quality* question.  Once you do this the question can be reopened.

You should not just re-post the question, no.